# How to register a ValidationEventHandler with Moxy in Jersey?

Tags: java, rest, jaxb, jersey, moxy

The [examples that I've found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26972237/how-to-configure-jaxb-moxy-to-throw-an-error-on-potential-lost-data-in-xml) talk about setting the validation handler on an `unmarshaller` object.

However, using Jersey, MOXy/JAXB is initialized for me and I don't know how to access the unmarshaller.

Currently, I bootstrap Jersey like this, with `jersey-media-moxy` being on the classpath.

```
@ApplicationPath("rest")
public class ApplicationConfig extends ResourceConfig {
    Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(ApplicationConfig.class);

    public ApplicationConfig() {
        // Scan classes in this package and subpackages
        logger.info("Registering REST Application");
        packages("rest");
        register(new AbstractBinder() {
            @Override
            protected void configure() {
                // used to automatically inject a Connection instance and close it
                bindFactory(ConnectionFactory.class).to(Connection.class)
                        .proxy(true).proxyForSameScope(false).in(RequestScoped.class);
            }
        });


    }
}
```

With this approach, how can I register a `ValidationEventHandler` on the unmarshaller?

Answer (score 2):

I don't know if this is the correct way to do this (I've never done it), but doing some digging around [the source code](https://github.com/jersey/jersey/tree/master/media/moxy/src/main/java/org/glassfish/jersey/moxy/json), you could just extend the `ConfigurableMoxyJsonProvider` and override the [`preReadFrom`](https://github.com/jersey/jersey/blob/2.26-b07/media/moxy/src/main/java/org/glassfish/jersey/moxy/json/internal/ConfigurableMoxyJsonProvider.java#L135).

I don't see any other way this can be done.  The previous class mentioned extends [`MoxyJsonProvider`](https://github.com/eclipse/eclipselink.runtime/blob/2.6.4/moxy/org.eclipse.persistence.moxy/src/org/eclipse/persistence/jaxb/rs/MOXyJsonProvider.java). You can see in the [`readFrom`](https://github.com/eclipse/eclipselink.runtime/blob/2.6.4/moxy/org.eclipse.persistence.moxy/src/org/eclipse/persistence/jaxb/rs/MOXyJsonProvider.java#L634), when the `Unmarahsaller` is created, there's not really much you can do with it. All you can do is set properties from the outside. But nothing that gives you access to the actual `Unmarshaller`. So maybe the only way to access it to just extend the provider.

You probably will also need to disable the default MOXy provider. For example

```
@Consumes("application/json")
@Produces("application/json")
public class ValidatingMoxyProvider extends ConfigurableMoxyJsonProvider {
    private final ValidationEventHandler handler = event -> {
        System.out.println(event.getLinkedException());
        System.out.println(event.getMessage());
        return false;
    };

    @Override
    protected void preReadFrom(final Class<Object> type, 
                               final Type genericType,
                               final Annotation[] annotations,
                               final MediaType mediaType,
                               final MultivaluedMap<String, String> httpHeaders,
                               final Unmarshaller unmarshaller) throws JAXBException {
        super.preReadFrom(type, genericType, annotations,
                          mediaType, httpHeaders, unmarshaller);
        unmarshaller.setEventHandler(handler);
    }
}

public ApplicationConfig() {
    register(ValidatingMoxyProvider.class);
    property(ServerProperties.MOXY_JSON_FEATURE_DISABLE, true);
}
```

If you're worried about what you might be disabling, just look at the [source for the MoxyJsonFeature](https://github.com/jersey/jersey/blob/2.26-b07/media/moxy/src/main/java/org/glassfish/jersey/moxy/json/MoxyJsonFeature.java). You're not really missing out on anything unless you're using the [entity filtering feature](https://jersey.github.io/documentation/latest/entity-filtering.html)